# AWS-Need to add Backtracking feature to the existing Aurora DB. How to do it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have existing Aurora DB for which Backtracking was not enabled during the creation. Now I want to add it. Looks like we cannot modify to add that feature now. How can I do it? Any guidance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS Doc says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Managing.Backtrack.html):

> Backtracking is only available for DB clusters that were created with the Backtrack feature enabled. You can enable the Backtrack feature when you create a new DB cluster or restore a snapshot of a DB cluster.

So you need to take a snapshot of your Aurora and [restore it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-restore-snapshot.html). You'll see the Enable Backtrack toggle in the Advanced setting section.